# How to return difference between two column values in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have 1 dataframe and want to check and then return the difference in values between two columns of the same dataframe only if there is a value in the 2nd column. The 2nd column in my example below is AppliancesO and first column is AppliancesH

```
Item Name           AppliancesH          AppliancesO 
1    Joe                     TV                   TV
2   Mary           [TV; Fridge]                   TV
3   Jack  [Microwave;TV;Fridge] [Computer;TV;Fridge]
4   Pete          [Fridge;Oven]
```

and 1000 more rows as such

The output am looking for is

```
Item Name           AppliancesH          AppliancesO                 Diff
1    Joe                     TV                   TV    
2   Mary           [TV; Fridge]                   TV               Fridge
3   Jack  [Microwave;TV;Fridge] [Computer;TV;Fridge] [Microwave;Computer]
4   Pete          [Fridge;Oven]
```

I know how to compare the columns to determine if they are different, but I dont know how to return the difference

```
df.loc[(df['AppliancesH']!=df['AppliancesO'])& ~df.AppliancesO.isna()][['Name','AppliancesH', 'AppliancesO','Diff']]
```

Comment: Is your representation formal ? What is, say, `[Microwave;TV;Fridge]`, a stringified list or a list that contains a string ?

Comment: It is a list of strings

Comment: The point is that, in python, list delimiters are [comma](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Comma.svg), not [semi-colon](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Semicolon.svg). So, at most, `[Microwave;TV;Fridge]` is a list that contains only one string, i.e. that contains `"Microwave;TV;Fridge"`.

Comment: ah, I see. I can change  it to a comma delimiter then. But still dont know how to get the result am looking for :(

Comment: What is not clear either, is why you are not dealing with heterogeneous-typed columns. Why are some data just strings, while some others are list of strings ?

Comment: I'm agree with @keepAlive. You should use a list of one element rather than a simple string. If you can change the separator `;` to `,`, so you can enclose your item (Fridge, TV, ...) by simple quotes. Like that, you have a real python list. After, the problem becomes trivial :-)

Comment: @keepAlive - how else would i show a record where a person has only 1 appliance?

Comment: Why not with a list that has only one component. [*Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id2).

Comment: Besides, what do you expect diff of [TV, TV, Fridge] and [TV]?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following data

```
>>> dict_ = {'AppliancesH': {1: ['TV'], 2: ['TV', 'Fridge'], 3: ['Microwave', 'TV', 'Fridge'], 4: ['Fridge', 'Oven']}, 'AppliancesO': {1: ['TV'], 2: ['TV'], 3: ['Computer', 'TV', 'Fridge'], 4: []}, 'Name': {1: 'Joe', 2: 'Mary', 3: 'Jack', 4: 'Pete'}}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict_)
>>> df
               AppliancesH             AppliancesO  Name
1                     [TV]                    [TV]   Joe
2             [TV, Fridge]                    [TV]  Mary
3  [Microwave, TV, Fridge]  [Computer, TV, Fridge]  Jack
4           [Fridge, Oven]                      []  Pete
```

You can use [`set`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp)'s [`~.symmetric_difference`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/symmetric_difference) to perform such operation. Let(s first define the callable we need:

```
def symdif(s: pd.Series) -> list:
    h = s.AppliancesH
    o = s.AppliancesO
    return h and o and sorted(set(h).symmetric_difference(o))
```

and use it via [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
>>> df['Diff'] = df.apply(axis=1, func=symdif)
>>> df
               AppliancesH             AppliancesO  Name                   Diff
1                     [TV]                    [TV]   Joe                     []
2             [TV, Fridge]                    [TV]  Mary               [Fridge]
3  [Microwave, TV, Fridge]  [Computer, TV, Fridge]  Jack  [Computer, Microwave]
4           [Fridge, Oven]                      []  Pete                     []
```

Comment: Any question [@user3423407](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3423407/user3423407) ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
df['Differences'] = (df.set_index('Name')
                     .applymap(set)
                     .apply(lambda x: set.symmetric_difference(*x),axis=1).map(list)
                     .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with XOR operator

```
def find_diff(row):
    if row.isna().any():
        return []
    
    diff = set(row['AppliancesH']) ^ set(row['AppliancesO'])
    return list(diff)
    
df.apply(find_diff, axis=1)
```

You might also need to write a function that converts those strings to a list